# При преобразовании программы Python в .exe, она очень много весит

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Сделал небольшую програмку для показа погоды на pyqt5. Общий вес проекта около 800 Кб. Я использовал pyinstaller, чтобы собрать exe. У меня создалась папка dist весом 645 Мб.
На картинке ниже часть библиотек, которые добавились в мой проект, но я импортировал только PyQt5, sys и pyowm

**как можно уменьшить вес проекта?**

[image: Вот картинка]

Comment: Целиком PyQT5 импортировали или определенные модули?

Comment: Определенные, такого типа: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget`

Comment: Может нужно использовать виртуальную среду с нужными модулями?

Comment: Переписать на С++, и можно даже без QT.

Comment: ну такого быть явно не должно, попробуйте пересобрать, указывая правильные флаги -F -w

Comment: Размер уменьшился до 234 Мб, но время открытия секунд 10-15

Comment: pyside6-deploy попробуйте.